# Invoking a function with different amount of input than the function takes

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, function

```js
function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return sub(a, b, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
    }
```

```js
    function sub(
        uint256 a,
        uint256 b,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a - b;

        return c;
    }
```

```
_allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(
                amount,
                "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"
            )
        );
```

Here is the `sub` function that is invoked, only two arguments are passed to it, but the `sub` function takes in 3 arguments.
How is the code working?

Comment: can you provide the contract address and the chain this is happening on? The contract could have multiple functions named `sub`, and the other one could have only 2 arguments.

Comment: the sub function is from the open-zepplin's safemath library , chain is bep-20

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this `sub` function is copied from OpenZeppelin's [`SafeMath.sol` library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v3.4/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol), or similar.

In Solidity, you can declare special [`library` functions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/contracts.html#libraries) by declaring functions inside a `library` (instead of a `contract`):

```
library MyLibrary {
  function myLibraryFunction() // This is a library function
}

contract MyContract {
  function myFunction() // This is a normal function
}
```

Library functions differ from normal functions in that you can use the [`using for` directive](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/contracts.html#using-for) to attach library functions to a type. Like this:

```
using SafeMath for uint256;
```

Once a library is attached to a type, you can call the library functions directly on objects of that type. **The object you call a library function on is passed as the first argument of the library function.**

So this code:

```
_allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds allowance");
```

Is effectively equivalent to:

```
sub(_allowances[sender][_msgSender()], amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds allowance");
```